# R data.table regression by group when some groups contain only missing values

Tags: r, data.table

I am attempting to get the residuals for regressions by group using data.table:

```
DT[, res := lm(y ~ x)$resid, by = groups]
```

There can be missing values in both `x` and `y` scattered across the data set. The issue is, if a particular group contains only `NA` in either `x` or `y`, `lm` understandably throws this error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Is there a clever way to somehow catch this error and fill the output residuals with `NA` instead of failing on this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply consider only the complete cases. The `NA` values will be created by `[.data.table`.

This will also take care of when there are some missing values.

```
DT[complete.cases(DT[,list(x,y)], 
    res := residuals(lm(y ~ x, .SD)), by = groups]
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your call to `lm` in a `tryCatch` expression, like so:

```
tryCatch(lm(y ~ x)$resid, error=function(e) NA_real_)
```

For example:

```
DT <- data.table(data.frame(groups=rep(c('a', 'b'), each=3), x=rnorm(6), y=rnorm(6)))
setkey(DT, groups)
DT['b', y := NA_real_]
DT[, res := tryCatch(lm(y ~ x)$resid, error=function(e) NA_real_), by = groups]
#    groups       x       y      res
# 1:      a -0.9224  1.1080  0.07531
# 2:      a  0.5573 -0.6185 -0.94221
# 3:      a  0.6858  1.1290  0.86690
# 4:      b  1.3894      NA       NA
# 5:      b -1.0110      NA       NA
# 6:      b -0.4996      NA       NA
```

You may want to create an error catching function that will print the errors as well, so that you can verify they are all instances of missing data:

```
e.catch <- function(e) {message('lm error msg: ', e);NA_real_}
DT[, res := tryCatch(lm(y ~ x)$resid, error=e.catch), by = groups]
```

Or raise a different error if caused by something other than missing data:

```
e.catch <- function(e) if (grepl('non-NA', e)) NA_real_ else stop(e)
```